What to do with a Duplicate Record Sets when not a duplicate?
I'm going through my Duplicate Record Sets on the Account object and I'm wondering what best practice is regarding when the records are NOT a duplicate. Should I delete the duplicate Record Set? Will this mean a new Duplicate Record Set will be created in it's place as soon as one of the items is edited? Is there perhaps some benefit to keeping the record set around?
Another option is I can create a checkbox on the accounts that indicate this is not a duplicate, and then have the Matching Rule or Duplicate Rule not trigger when that is true. This feels a little messy though.

Do nothing is a good option.

Salesforce doesn't bring any logic to exclude something from the duplicate checks manually - if you want that you would need a 3rd party product or roll your own.
Of course, you can also always delete the record sets or record items but if the rules haven't changed they will still get matched as a duplicate eventually, so it really depends on your use case if this is an option for you.
You can also approach this via the report side to exclude certain record sets or record items from the report when a checkbox is checked. Technically this will still keep the record as a duplicate but it will not show up on the records. For example - I added a rule that excludes duplicate record sets with only one item left. That way nobody has to delete anything.
What you get out of the box isn't perfect but as usual, you have many ways to customize it. I get that the checkbox feels a bit messy but at the end of the day, the solution just needs to work. :)
